# Integration of a $2$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

What is

$$\int_C{\omega}$$

where $\omega=\frac{dx \wedge dy}{x^2+y^2}$ and $C(t_1,t_2)=(t_1+1)(\cos(2\pi t_2),\sin(2\pi t_2)) : I_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 - \text{{(0,0)}}$?

The integrals of $1$-forms I understood as we take $dx$ and $dy$ as the derivatives of the parametrisation $C(t)$ w.r.t $t$. However for $2$-forms we now have the wedge product $dx \wedge dy$ which is where my problem lies in this question. Is this a matter of differentiation in two variables when computing this wedge? For example, before even calculating the wedge product, what is $dx(t_1,t_2)$?

The denominator isn't a problem: $x^2+y^2 = (t_1+1)^2$

Comment: Have you tried something? If so include it in your post.

Comment: I have updated to show where I'm up to; not far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen a definition of the integral of a $2$-form along a "2D path" $C: I^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (has anyone?), but it seems clear to me that the sensible definition should be

$$ \int_C \omega := \int_{I^2} C^*\omega$$

where $C^*\omega$ is the pull-back of $\omega$ by $C$. Recall that it is defined by
$$ (C^*\omega)_{|p} (u, v) := \omega_{|C(p)}(dC_{|p} (u), dC_{|p} (v))~.$$

NB: More generally, we could define the same way integrals $\int_C \omega$ where $\omega$ is a $k$-form on a $k$-dimensional manifold $M$ and $c$ is a smooth map $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k \to M$.

Let's come back to your problem. Practically, you can compute $C^* \omega$ by letting $(x,y) = C(t_1,t_2)$ in the expression of $\omega$, you get:

$$
\begin{align*}
x &= (t_1 + 1) \cos (2\pi t_2)\\
y &= (t_1 + 1) \sin (2\pi t_2) \\
\end{align*}
$$

hence

$$
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 &= (t_1+1)^2\\
dx &= \cos (2\pi t_2)\,dt_1 - 2\pi (t_1 + 1)\sin(2\pi t_2) dt_2\\
dy &= \sin (2\pi t_2)\,dt_1 + 2\pi (t_1 + 1)\cos(2\pi t_2) dt_2\\
dx \wedge dy &= 2\pi (t_1+1)\, dt_1\wedge dt_2\\
\end{align*}
$$
thus
$$
C^* \omega = {2\pi\, dt_1\wedge dt_2\over t_1 +1}
$$
You can now easily compute your integral: assuming $I = [0,1]$ (you don't say what I is)
$$
\int_C \omega = \int_{I^2}{2\pi\, dt_1\wedge dt_2\over t_1 +1} = \int_{I^2}{2\pi\, dt_1 dt_2\over t_1 +1}
$$
which gives us by Tonelli's theorem
$$
\int_C \omega = 2\pi\left(\int_{0}^1{dt_1\over t_1 +1}\right)\left(\int_{0}^1 dt_2\right) = 2\pi \log (2)
$$

NB: Another approach ("just for fun") would be to work in polar coordinates, I'll let you try to figure out how do that.

Comment: Having thought about your last point about polar coordinates, I wouldn't even know where to start. Any hint?

Comment: Well, given that $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\in\theta$, can you express $C$, $dx$, $dy$ and $\omega$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ ?

Comment: The only way I can interpret what you mean is $r=(t_1+1)$ and $\theta = 2\pi t_2$. Am I being naive here or are you just suggesting substitutions? From what I can see, we're already working in polar coordinates looking at our $C$.

Comment: That's right, now you should try to express everything in those coordinates as I suggested above

Comment: Searching "integral 2-form" gives your answer. You should expand on $(C^*\omega)_{|p} (u, v)$, for a function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ and a surface $C=\{c(u,v) \in \Bbb{R}^n,(u,v)\in[0,1]^2\}$ then $C^*df=df(c(u,v))=(\partial_uf(c(u,v)))du+(\partial_vf(c(u,v))) dv$ with $du\land dv=-dv\land du$ we have
$C^* df\land dg=h(u,v)du\land dv$ where $h=(\partial_uf\circ c)(\partial_v g\circ c)-(\partial_ug\circ c)(\partial_vf\circ c)$ and 
$\int_C df\land dg=\int_0^1 (\int_0^1 h(u,v)du)dv$. Claim: up to an orientation sign $\int_Cdf \land dg$ doesn't depend on the chosen parametrization of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to polar coordinates, let $t_1+1=r\in[1,2]$, and $2\pi t_2=\phi\in[0,2\pi]$ (full circle). The set $C$ is an *annulus* in the $x,y$ plane bounded by the two concentric circles $r=1,2$, with $x^2+y^2=(r\cos\phi)^2+(r\sin\phi)^2=r^2$ The surface element $dx\wedge dy = r dr d \phi$. The function depends only on $r$, so the integration over the angle gives us simply $2\pi$, and finally the result is

$$2\pi\int_1^2 \frac{rdr}{r^2}=2\pi\log2$$